# awk command to check condition from first field of first row and second field of first row

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have comma separated fields as below which is the output from `nodestat` command.

```
node mode  : produce ,  modify time: 2014-11-22 04:23:28
node status: active  ,  modify time: 2014-11-22 04:23:28
```

I want to print "OK" if all below conditions seen:

1. "node mode  : produce" (first row first column) and
2. "node status: active" (second row first column) and
3. modify time is less than yesterday time.(second column in first and second row)

Otherwise print "NOT OK".

Comment: It is unclear under what circumstances "OK" and "Not OK" should be produced. Does both times have to be the same? Does both lines have to have a timestamp more than 24h in the past. Is it enough to have a timestamp before most recent midnight? Are there more similar lines in the data?

Comment: @Kusalananda :  Timestamp should be before day-1. both times can have same or different. it is not required in condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write below short `awk` script for this:

```
nodestat |awk -v Yday="$(date -d "$(date -d '-1day' '+%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" +%s)" -F"[ ,]" \
   '{ Mdate=$(NF-1)" "$NF; 
      dMepoch="date -d""\""Mdate"\""" +%s";
      dMepoch |getline Mdate; close(dMepoch)
    }
    $0 ~ /node mode  : produce/ && NR==1 && Mdate<Yday{tru++;next}
    {print($0 ~ /node status: active/ && NR==2 && Mdate<Yday && tru)?"OK":"NOT OK";exit
}'
OK
```

#### Explanation:

- In `$(date -d "$(date -d '-1day' '+%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" +%s)`, first we are getting yesterday's date in this format `Y-m-d 00:00:00` by `$(date -d '-1day' '+%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')`, then converting it to [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and assign to variable called `Yday`.
- In `F"[ ,]"`, we are defining filed separator as both *comma* and *space*.
- In `Mdate=$(NF-1)" "$NF;`, based on filed separator, we are taking last two fields into a variable called `Mdate` which contains only *date*, then;
- In `dMepoch="date -d""\""Mdate"\""" +%s";`, we set a shell command as `date -d""\""Mdate"\""" +%s` and assign to a variable called `dMepoch`; and with `dMepoch |getline Mdate;` we call previous command [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe) with the value of `Mdate` passing into it to get its epoch and keep in same `Mdate` variable too, then;
- At the end we need to close the command we opened, so we used [`close(dMepoch)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) to close it.

Now we have both yesterday's date and date for each row of `nodestat` in epoch every line `awk` will read. Later by

- `$0 ~ /node mode  : produce/ && NR==1 && Mdate<Yday{tru++;next}`, we are checking if it's first line `NR==1` and modify time (epoch saved in `Mdate`) is older than yesterday's date (epoch in `Yday`) and line contains `node mode  : produce`, then set a flag `tru++` and run `awk` for `next` line, so
- In `print($0 ~ /node status: active/ && NR==2 && Mdate<Yday && tru)?"OK":"NOT OK";exit`, we are choking the same modify time in second line `NR==2` and contains our match and also if all condition was meet in first line `tru!=0`, then print "OK", otherwise print "NOT OK" by ternary condition `print (condition)?if_true:if_false`. The `exit` is used to here whenever if first line doesn't meet the conditions and at first run of `awk` it will print "NOT OK" and exit that will prevent duplicating "NOT OK"s.

Comment: could you please explain the above awk script.

Comment: Yes, I will do it. Is this worked for you and what you were expecting?

Comment: yes it's working. Thanks. kindly explain as well.

Comment: Well, see my update.

Comment: i want to check this awk command in cshell. but it's giving variable error. could you please fix it?